# iOS: Set up the navigation controller to use GTScrollNavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I am using StoryBoard, I've added a UITableViewController and then embedded it with navigation bar.

Now, I want to implement [GTScrollNavigationBar](https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar)
 in my application, in Usage section, it says : `Set up the navigation controller to use GTScrollNavigationBar`

how can I do that in my .m ?

Thnaks in advance

Comment: If I copy&paste the "Usage" section in the link you provided, are you going to mark my answer as accepted?  There's also an example project located in the link in your question that should show you exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the navigation controller to use GTScrollNavigationBar:

```
#import "GTScrollNavigationBar.h"

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:  
    [GTScrollNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[self.navController setViewControllers:@[self.mainViewController] animated:NO];
```

In your view controller which has a UIScrollView, e.g. UITableViewController, set the UIScrollView object to the GTScrollNavigationBar in viewWillAppear: by:

```
self.navigationController.scrollNavigationBar.scrollView = self.tableView;
```

To unfollow the scrollView, simply set scrollView property to nil

```
self.navigationController.scrollNavigationBar.scrollView = nil;
```

Implement scrollViewDidScrollToTop: in the view controller to reset the navigation bar's position

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.navigationController.scrollNavigationBar resetToDefaultPosition:YES];
}
```

[Source.](https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar)

Comment: Well, I actually added navigation bar to my viewController in story board, so when I COPY above code, Xcode gives me a warning "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UINavigationItem' from 'UINavigationController'"

Comment: also I dont want to alloc navigation bar from appdelegate.

Comment: What you have tried shouldn't be posted in a comment to an answer.  It should be part of the original question.